# Why is my virtual function "unique" nor working?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, virtual

I have two virtual functions in my Base Class, but one of them is not working. I have no idea what's wrong with it. Will anyone please help me?

I've tried changing the virtual method "unique" to a pure virtual method, it throws an error saying "pure virtual function not defined". "Print" seems to work fine, but "unique" is not working.

````
#include <iostream>
#include "polymor.h"

void print (std::vector<Base *> b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); ++i)
    {
      b[i]->print();
      b[i]->unique();
    }
}

int main()
{
  std::vector< Base * > pointers;
  Base * b1 = new Derived1();
  Base * b2 = new Derived2();
  pointers.push_back(b1);
  pointers.push_back(b2);
  print (pointers);
  return 0;
}

//polymor.h:

#ifndef POLYMOR_H
#define POLYMOR_H

#include <iostream>
class Base
{
public:
  virtual void print()
  {
    std::cout << "Base\n";
  }
  virtual void unique()
  {
    std::cout << "BaseUnique\n";
  };
};

class Derived1: public Base
{
public:
  void print()
  {
    std::cout << "Derived1\n";
  }
  void unqiue()
  {
    std::cout << "Der1Unique\n";
  }
};

class Derived2: public Base
{
  void unqiue()
  {
    std::cout << "Der2Unique\n";
  }
};
#endif```

This is my output:

Derived1
BaseUnique
Base
BaseUnique
````

Comment: Welcome to SO, and thanks for starting out with an actual [mcve]!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a typo in your derived class - note that “unique” is spelled incorrectly.

A great way to diagnose this sort of issue quickly: mark all member functions that are supposed to be overrides with the `override` modifier. That way, if you make a typo like this, the compiler will flag it as an error rather than resulting in weird runtime issues. For example, this won’t compile:

```
void unqiue() override // Nothing named "unqiue" to override 
{
  std::cout << "Der1Unique\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works like a charm. :)

Comment: Did you really have to answer a typo question?

Comment: @SergeyA In this case, I figured that the real issue was not the typo, but rather the lack of the `override` on the function. I hoped that providing this detail would both immediately address the issue and provide guidance in the future.

Comment: I apologize for this simple error, but I learned about the **override**. It will definitely help me in the future.

Comment: No worries! In fact, one of the reasons that `override` was added to the language was because this specific error is (1) common, (2) hard to diagnose, and (3) leads to very unusual behavior.